# proving boundedness of a linear functional

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $f$ be a linear functional on a normed vector space V and $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed. Prove that $f$ is bounded

Comment: I haven't progressed much. I was trying if I could get some bounds on $f(x)$ when $||x|| = 1$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan any help in solving the problem is appreciated. thanks

Comment: I don't think it is bounded in general...

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld A linear map with finite-dimensional range is continuous if and only if its kernel is closed.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, I did not think to look up what it meant for a *linear functional* to be bounded. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just quotient by $\ker(f) = f^{-1}(\{0\})$. This is a closed subspace, so the quotient is a normed linear space, and the quotient map $\pi : X \to X/\ker(f)$ is continuous. Now $f$ induces a non-zero map
$$
\overline{f} : X/\ker(f) \to \mathbb{K}
$$
(where $\mathbb{K}$ is the ground field) such that $f = \overline{f}\circ \pi$. Now check that $\overline{f}$ is an isomorphism (because $\ker(f)$ is a hyperplane). Thus, $f$ is forced to be continuous.

Comment: why is ker(f) a hyperplane?

Comment: Can you please explain why $\bar{f}$ is an isomorphism

Comment: Choose any $x_0 \in X$ such that $\alpha = f(x_0) \neq 0$. Then for any $x \in X$, for $\beta = f(x)$, check that $x - (\beta/\alpha)x_0 \in \ker(f)$. Hence, $X/\ker(f)$ is one-dimensional.

Comment: $\overline{f}$ is an isomorphism because it is a non-zero linear map between two one-dimensional spaces.